# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7-x64

I recently uninstalled SQL Server 2012 Express, including deleting all (I think) relevant files.

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 developers edition on my laptop (Windows 7), but when I open Management Studio the server name is blank, and I get connection errors when trying to login using `localhost`, `MSSQLSERVER`, etc...  (Error 18456)

SQL Server Configuration Manager is showing `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` as active.

Installation notes;

- Default instance (`MSSQLSERVER`)
- In `Server Configuration` I selected "Use the same account for all SQL Server services" (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM)
- In "Engine Configuration" I selected windows authentication
- Windows account used to install is not an admin account

Comment: You should have configured the `sa` account when you installed.  Can you login using those credentials?  Obvious question, but the SQL service is started, right?

Comment: SQL service is showing as started, I tried a fresh install on my admin account using mixed authentication but the errors persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx).

If your error message looks like this:

> Msg 18456, Level 14, **State 1**, Server , Line 1 Login
>   failed for user ''

you need to look at the state part of the error message to find out the cause of the issue.

Anyway it will be better if you provide the full error message.

Comment: Did an uninstall and installed SQL Express 2008 R2 today, configured with mixed authentication, but still the same.  The error I get is:    An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: Also now when opening Management Studio a window pops up with the following:  The automatically saved settings file "C:\Users\Me\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Settings\CurrentSettings-2014-12-04.vssettings" cannot be found.  You can change this file on the "Import and Export Settings" Tools Options page.  The IDE will use your most recent settings for this session.

Comment: It is a different error message.  Check this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/.

Comment: The key idea here: All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> Select TCP/IP.  But check firewall and service running also.

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to point out that the error message had changed with the new install.  Followed the TCP/IP Firewall steps in that link, after which I was able to log in using ".\SQLEXPRESS" as the server name.  I'll have some more time tomorrow to do some testing.  Thanks for the help.